# windows service -> batch file: access denied to stop the service

Tags: windows-services, permissions, batch-file

my service downloads an update, writes batch file and executes it by `system()` call. batch file stops the service, updates it and starts it back. everything works fine when I'm logged in as  administrator. under regular user I receive "access denied" to stop service.

I hoped batch file will be run under system account because is lauched by a service. But seems it isn't. Please explain why not. Any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could diagnose the problem by using the `runas` command from a terminal:

```
runas /user:mymachine\serviceaccount batchfile.bat
```

and also the `icacls` command to query and set the permissions:

```
icacls batchfile.bat
```

and look for the RX permission